# Detect change to modelValue in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

Is there a way to detect change to modelValue in a custom component? I want to push the change to a wysiwyg editor.

I tried watching modelValue but emitting update for modelValue triggered that watch, which created circular data flow.

Code:

```js
export default {
  props: ['modelValue'],
  watch: {
    modelValue (val) {
      this.editor.editor.loadHTML(val)
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.editor.editor.loadHTML(val)
    this.editor.addEventListener('trix-change', 
      (event) => this.$emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value))
  }
}
```

```html
<TextEditor v-model="someHtml"></TextEditor>
```

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: @Daniel: Added some code

Answer (score 13):

In VueJS v3, the event name for [custom v-model handling changed](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#using-v-model-on-components) to 'update:modelValue'.

You can listen to these events like this: `v-on:update:modelValue="handler"`

For a more complete example, lets assume you have a Toggle component with these properties/methods:

```js
...
props: {
        modelValue: Boolean,
},
data() {
    return {
        toggleState: false,
    };
},
methods: {
    toggle() {
        this.toggleState = !this.toggleState;
        this.$emit('update:modelValue', this.toggleState);
    }
}
...
```

You can use that Toggle component:

```js
<Toggle v-model="someProperty" v-on:update:modelValue="myMethodForTheEvent"/>
```

As a side note, you could also v-model on a computed property with a setter; allowing you to internalise your state changes without using the update:modelValue event. In this example, it assumes you `v-model="customProperty"` on your custom Toggle component.

```js
 computed: {
      customProperty: {
        get() {
          return this.internalProperty;
        },
        set(v) {
          this.internalProperty = v;
          console.log("This runs when the custom component 'updates' the v-model value.");
        },
      }
    },
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I might have been unclear in my question, but my problem was to detect change to `modelValue` in the component, in your example Toggle.

Comment: Using setter is not enough sometimes, esp when you need to pass more args along with the event.

Comment: `v-on:update:modelValue` can also be written as `@update:modelValue`

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and solved it using a slight tweak to the way you call the `watch` function:

```js
setup(props) {
      watch(() => props.modelValue, (newValue) => {
            // do something
      })
}
```

Hence, the important thing is to add `() => props.modelValue` instead of just putting `props.modelValue` as the first argument of the `watch` function.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  And, I had this need in the same scenario - wysiwyg editor prop.

Answer (score 1):

try that:

```js
  watch: {
...
   modelValue: function(val) {
   console.log('!!! model value changed ', val);
 },
...
```

Comment: See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Comment: How is this code different to the code in the question?